# How to create a local user account that does not belong to any group?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-management, account-management

Currently, I am creating a user with

```
var user = new UserPrincipal(localMachineContext, "MyUser1", "MyPassword", enabled: true);
user.Save();
```

However, new user is immediately included into "HomeUsers" group (Win10), which is undesired behavior. I can then go through all the groups in local machine, and remove this new user from them, but wonder if there's a better way to create the user, so it does not belong to any group initially?

Answer (score -1):

All new users automatically get added to the `Users` group. To make a user with no groups you would need to remove the user from the group after creation.

Comment: Well, surprisingly, new user is not added to Users, just to  HomeUsers

Comment: It depends on place you do it from I guess, when I went in to computer management and added the user that way it just added the `Users` group, however I did notice my own user was not in that group and was in the `HomeUsers` group.